# Praying salah sitting due to incontinence

Tags: salat, taharah, doubts, self-purification

Salam, I have urine incontinence and I normally go toilet an hour or a bit longer before my salah. I still get drops coming out when I read. What do I do? Do I continue to pray or should I pray sitting down to reduce any urine coming out. I do also have a thick amount of tissue stopping urine spread.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a chronic illness so I assume you’d be excused from few rulings but I’m not completely sure so please also try looking on other sites if you can

Comment: Other sites are saying the same. I’m going to the doctors to legally confirm it first then I’ll move from that